# generator polynomial of the intersection of two cyclic codes

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C_1, C_2$ be two cyclic codes over $GF(q)$ and $g_1(x), g_2(x)$ their generator polynomials.
$C_1$ is of [n,k], $C_2$ is of [n,m].

What is the generator polynomial of $C_1 \cap C_2$? I'm think the answer should be somewhere around $lcm(g_1, g_2)$ But so far I failed to show that it generates the codewords that exist both in $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Your hunch about lcm is correct. Listing the relevant concepts. If you are familiar with them, you can proceed: $GF(q)$ is a field, so $GF(q)[x]$ is a unique factorization domain. A word $c(x)$ is in $C_1$ if and only if it is divisible by $g_1(x)$. Similarly $c(x)$ is in $C_2$ if and only if it is divisible $g_2(x)$. Therefore $c(x)\in C_1\cap C_2$ if and only if it is divisible by both $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$.Uniqueness of factorization implies (standard pieces of theory here) that this happens if and only if $c(x)$ is divisible by $\text{lcm}(g_1(x),g_2(x))$.

Comment: (cont'd) Them being words of cyclic codes further constrains that the polynomial should be of degree $<n$, but that does not affect the flow of the logic.

Comment: In some places they teach this material while only glossing over some concepts from algebra. This is not your fault - engineering programs in particular don't have time to do this with the same level of detail a pure math program has. And students in math programs may have forgotten some of those details because the theory was not necessarily put to use in their very next course. Therefore some of the steps above may be unclear to you. Can you pinpoint such steps (if any).